# IndexError: list index out of range in a function using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, tkinter, beautifulsoup, indexoutofrangeexception

I am making a GUI based project in Python with the module tkinter. It fetches basic data from online judge, eg, SPOJ using Beautiful Soup. I am a newbie in Python, so most of the things I have written is with basic tutorials from internet. However, for a particular piece of code, I am totally stuck up.

```
import sys
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re

userName = 'xilinx'
spojUrl = 'http://www.spoj.com/users/'+userName

with urllib.request.urlopen(spojUrl) as x:
   html = x.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# li - list of successful submissions
li = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-condensed')[0].find_all('td')
listOfSolvedProblemCodes = []
    for submission in li:
        problemCode = submission.get_text()
        if problemCode:
            listOfSolvedProblemCodes.append(problemCode)
print (userName+ ' has solved',len(listOfSolvedProblemCodes),'problems on Spoj.')
```

This part of code works fine when I run it with python submissions.py

After testing this part, I try to incorporate it into the larger code, where the problem arises. I am including here the relevant section of the code:

In frame.py:

```
def compStats ():
    if ch == "SPOJ":
        stats.show(ch, userName)

B2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="My Statistics", command=compStats)
B2.place(anchor = W, x = 30, y = 220, width=200)
```

In stats.py:

```
def show(ch, userName):

    if ch == 'SPOJ':

        spojUrl = 'http://www.spoj.com/users/'+userName

        with urllib.request.urlopen(spojUrl) as x:
            html = x.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        li = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-condensed')[0].find_all('td')
        listOfSolvedProblemCodes = []
        for submission in li:
            problemCode = submission.get_text()
            if problemCode:
                listOfSolvedProblemCodes.append(problemCode)


    # then collect more information from soup and print it through labels in another window

    det = tkinter.Tk()
    det.title("Statistics")
    det.geometry("800x600")
```

But the problem of IndexError occurs in `stats.py` in the line:

```
li = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-condensed')[0].find_all('td')
```

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init
>   **.py", line 1550, in __call**
>
> return self.func(*args)
>
> File "frame.py", line 34, in compStats
>
> stats.show(ch, userName)
>
> File "C:\Users\Aa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\stats.py",
>   line 17, in show
>
> li = soup.find_all('table', class_='table
>   table-condensed')[0].find_all('td')
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I am unable to understand why the code is unable to work here. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step in debugging this is to take the complex line that is throwing an error and make it simpler. You can then inspect the intermediate values so see if the assumptions you're making about the code are true. In this case, your assumption is that `soup.find_all('table', ...)` is actually finding something.

For example, change this:

```
li = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-condensed')[0].find_all('td')
```

to this:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='table table-condensed')
li = tables[0].find_all('td')
```

Next, add a print statement to examine `tmp`:

```
print("tables is", tables)
```

You will find that `tables` is likely empty, so when you try to do `tables[0]` you get an error since index `0` is out of range.

Comment: I tried the approach you have suggested and found the same problem, that the tables is empty. But from the html file, I know that the tables should not be empty. And the same thing gets confirmed when I run this piece of code separately, it gives the answer 3138, i.e, the number of problems solved, and in this case, also the number of td tags. Hence, the confusion. Why is the same piece of code behaving differently?

Comment: For the same reason, I have put the full code that I run separately and get the answer. So that others could also run it and check. But once I put it into the function, it shows the error of index out of bounds.

Comment: @Neha: if you are getting different outputs, you are probably giving different inputs. Have you verified your assumption that you're giving the same inputs in all cases -- not just the same variable names, but the actual content of the variables? Maybe `username` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Thank you, so much! Being a newbie to Python, the scope of variables is getting me stuck in a lot of places, so much so that I am not even able to realize that it could be the reason! Will get this figured out now. :)

Comment: @Neha: first step to debug any problem: validate your assumptions.